# What is the source package for wxBase on Fedora 18?

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

I want to build the 2.9.x version of wxWidgets on Fedora 18, but I can't find the source package for wxBase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [apps.fedoraproject.org](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/s/wxBase) it is part of the wxGTK package.